# Second order coupled ODE using ODEINT

Tags: python, scipy

I am new to solving coupled ODEs with python, I am wondering if my approach is correct, currently this code outputs a graph that looks nothing like the expected output. These are the equations I am trying to solve:

[image]

And here is the code I am using (for the functions `f_gr`, `f_sc_phi` and `f_gTheta` you can just put any constant value)

```
import Radial as rd
import ScatteringAzimuthal as sa
import PolarComponent as pc
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#gamma for now set to 1
g_mm = 1

def f(u,t):
    #y1 = thetadot ::  y2 = phidot  ::  y3 = cdot
    rho, theta, y1, phi, y2, c, y3 = u
    p = [y1, (pc.f_gTheta(theta,524.1+rho)/(c*np.cos(phi))-(g_mm*y1)+(2*y1*y2*np.tan(phi))-(2*y3*y1/c)), 
         y2, ((sa.f_sc_phi(theta,524.1+rho/c))-(g_mm*y2)-(2*y3*y2/c)-(np.sin(phi)*np.cos(phi)*y2**2)), 
         y3, (rd.f_gr(theta,524.1+rho)-(g_mm*y3)+(c*y2**2)+(c*(y1**2)*(np.cos(phi)**2))), phi]
    return p

time = np.linspace(0,10,100)
z2 = odeint(f,[0.1,np.pi/2,0.1,np.pi/2,0.1,0.1,0.1], time)

rhoPl = z2[:,0]
thetaPl = z2[:,1]
phiPl = z2[:,3]

'''
plt.plot(rhoPl,time)
plt.plot(thetaPl,time)
plt.plot(phiPl,time)
plt.show()

'''

x = rhoPl*np.sin(thetaPl)*np.cos(phiPl)
y = rhoPl*np.sin(thetaPl)*np.sin(phiPl)
z = rhoPl*np.cos(thetaPl)

plt.plot(x,time)
plt.plot(y,time)
plt.plot(z,time)
plt.show()
```

when I change the time from 0.1 to 5 I get an error:

> ODEintWarning: Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type). Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.

Any ideas on how to improve this code or if my approach is completely incorrect?

Code for Radial.py

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import spherical_jn
from scipy.special import spherical_yn
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
R_r = 5.6*10**(-5) 
l = 720
n_w = 1.326
#k = 524.5/R_r
X_r = 524.5



# R is constant r is changing  
def f_gr(theta,x):
    f = ((sp.sin(theta))**(2*l-2))*(1+(sp.cos(theta))**2)
    b = (spherical_jn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_jn(l,n_w*x,True))+(spherical_yn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*x,True))
    c = (spherical_jn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_jn(l,n_w*X_r,True))+(spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r,True))
    n = b/c
    f = f*n
    return f
```

Code for ScatteringAzimuthal.py

```
from scipy.special import spherical_jn, spherical_yn
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = 720
n_w = 1.326
n_p = 1.572
X_r = 524.5
R_r = 5.6*10**(-5)
R_p = 7.5*10**(-7)
k = X_r/R_r


def f_sc_phi(theta,x):
    f = (2/3)*(n_w**2)*((X_r**3)/x)*((R_p**3)/(R_r**3))*(((n_p**2)-(n_w**2))/((n_p**2)+(2*(n_w**2))))
    g = np.sin(theta)**(2*l-3)
    numerator = (l*(1+np.sin(theta))- np.cos(2*theta))\
                *((spherical_jn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_jn(l,n_w*x))+(spherical_yn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*x)))
    denominator = ((spherical_jn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_jn(l,n_w*X_r,True))\
                   +(spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r,True)))
    m = numerator/denominator
    final = f*g*m
    return final
```

And Code for PolarComponent.py

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import spherical_yn, spherical_jn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l = 720
n_w = 1.326
X_r = 524.5 #this value is implemented in the ode file

#define dimensionless polar component
#X_r is radius, x is variable 
def f_gTheta(theta,x):
    bessel1 = (spherical_jn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_jn(l,n_w*x)) + \
              (spherical_yn(l,n_w*x)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*x))
    bessel2 = ((spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r,True)) + \
              (spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r)*spherical_yn(l,n_w*X_r,True)))*n_w*x
    bessels = bessel1/bessel2
    rest = (np.sin(theta)**(2*l-3))*((l-1)*(1+(np.cos(theta)**2)) \
                                     -((np.sin(theta)**2)*np.cos(theta)))
    final = rest*bessels
    return final
```

Comment: By looking at the problem equations, your y2 equation might have wrong perentesis. ((sa.f_sc_phi(theta,524.1+rho/c))  --> ((sa.f_sc_phi(theta,524.1+rho`)`/c)

Comment: thank you I fixed that! but this did not fix the error I am having when time is longer than 0.1 any ideas whats causing that error?

Comment: Could you provide some numbers for `pc.f_gTheta(theta,524.1+rho)`, `sa.f_sc_phi(theta,524.1+rho)`, `f_gr(theta,524.1+rho)` so that I can try it on my end?

Comment: Hi I have added all the files that I have for the three values! thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [link](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SecondOrderOptimization) that I really like for simulating second order odes. It has an optamization twist on it because it is fitting the model to match a simulation. It has a couple of examples for odeint and also gekko.